# Eventhandler in Bootstrapper

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container

I've the following code in App.xaml.cs in my wpf app.

```
public partial class App: Application
{
protected overrider void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
base.OnStartup(e);

base.Activated += App_Activated;
base.DeActivated += App_DeActivated;

new BootStrapper1().Run(true);
}
}

class BootStrapper1: UnityBootstrapper
{
void OnClosing(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

Is it possible to get access to Activated and DeActivated eventhandlers in  OnClosing method ?

Thanks.

Comment: How much memory will it leak?

Comment: `App.Current.Activated` ?